# SQL displaying wrong records in OR condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am struggling to write query for the below scenario, can any one help me please?

I have two column error and priority both are numeric fields. need to fetch based on the condition. If i select the value 3 for example from UI screen, it has to look for record in the table.

if the value match in any of the column i have to return the record i have written like this

```
Select * 
  FROM WorkItems 
 WHERE [System.Title] like '%defect%' 
   AND [System.WorkItemType] in ('Incident','bug') 
   AND [ErrorClass] =3 
    OR [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] =3 
   AND [Customer] = 'XYZ' 
 order by [System.WorkItemType]
```

Its giving false record and fetching all the records with priority or errorclass = 3, i need the records only workitem type = incident or bug for error class=3 or priority = 3

its returning all the records from the table.

If i put and condition like this `[ErrorClass] = 3` and `[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] = 3` its returning only if both the value are 3. I need all the records which match 3 along with above condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
Select *
  FROM WorkItems
 WHERE System.Title like '%defect%'
   AND System.WorkItemType in ('Incident', 'bug')
   AND (ErrorClass = 3 OR Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority = 3)    
   AND Customer = 'XYZ'
 order by System.WorkItemType
```

Comment: Just to add to this, so the OP learns something. The brackets added in the where clause disrupt the chain of logic. So instead of saying it is AND OR for every condition, you can break it down with brackets to have an OR clause within an AND clause, if you will.

Comment: The oprder of operations is that ANd conditions will be evaluated first and then OR caonditions. THis is critical to know as it makes a difference in the results. It is a best practice to  enclose things in () (which are higher in the order of operations than the AND Clause) when you mix AND and OR to make sure your intent was clear.